# Powershell Regex \d{n} Confusion

Tags: windows, powershell, regex

I'm messing around with simple regex filtering in Powershell, and I can't seem to get the digit \d expression to work properly.  I have a Test Directory with multiple files using 2 naming conventions - "AA### and AA####".  Some with 3 digits, some with 4.  I want to be able to search for anything starting with "AA" but only with 3 trailing digits.  Below is the command:

`get-childitem -Path "$HOME\documents\Test Directory" | where {$_.Name -match "AA\d{3}"}`

According to Microsoft's documentation, the {n} quantifier will "Match EXACTLY n number of times", however my problem is that it searches a minimum of {3} digits, and more, so it displays files with 3+ digits after the "AA".  When I specify the file extension "AA\d{3}.txt" it works fine, but I want this to work if the user does not know the file extension - allowing them to search any file with the specified naming convention.

Is there a different way to explicitly specify no more than 3 as the digit quantifier?

Comment: Then check the `BaseName` without extension and anchor the RE also at the end of the input `|Where-Object BaseName -match '^AA\d{3}$'` Note: simple expressions don't need a script block.  Alternatively you could exclude further digits with a negative lookahead: `|Where-Object Name -match '^AA\d{3}(?>!\d)'`

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks, the [.] worked as it just enters the file extension.  I think I'll stick with the suggestion to end in [^\d] as it denotes to end at the end of the 3 digits, regardless of if it's a folder or file with an extension.

Comment: Be sure to accept the answer that helped you resolve by checking the gray arrow to the top left on the answer you accept and turning it green. This gives them credit for their work if it helped you resolve..

Comment: @LotPings I was able to get the anchor to work with BaseName, but noticed I had to remove the script block for BaseName.  Is there any substitute for it in a script block?

Comment: As I mentioned for simple expressions the script block is not necessary, when you **want** to use it prepend BaseName with `$_.BaseName`. BTW the other variant works but the `>` is wrong and has to be omitted.

Comment: @LotPings Unfortunately I will require a script block, as this is just a test that will eventually make its way into a much larger script where the `Where-Object` pipe will require a script block.  I didn't know about BaseName, so I had no idea I could append it with $_., so that'll work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that

```
AA\d{3}
```

should match exactly three digits after `AA`.
In RegEx, there is no other way to express that.

If more than three digits are matched, this can be due to the reason that the matching expression does not end after that expression.
So

```
AA123
```

would match. And

```
AA1234
```

would also match, because it matches `AA123` and the rest of the string is just ignored. So, one possibility to match only `AA123` could be

```
AA\d{3}$
```

where `$` matches the end of line.
But there are other possibilities, too:
For example, you can terminate your matching on a *non-digit* like that:

```
AA\d{3}[^\d]
```

Comment: When anchoring at the end, switch to using the BaseName - otherwise any extension won't match.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should look like `\d(3)[^\d]`, for the fourth character after 3 digits
to not be a digit.

This won't work for the last line if it contains only `AA###` without an end-of-line.